# why does posix-spawn force to use vfork in linux?

Tags: ruby, linux

I have looked into the code of posix-spawn( https://github.com/rtomayko/posix-spawn), it seems that it uses vfork in the low level implementation.However, vfork is not encouraged to use in linux platform.Is it ok with posix-spawn module ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vfork` isn't recommended because it heavily restricts what the new process can do (until it `exec`s) and is consequently hard to use correctly. On Linux, `fork` uses copy-on-write semantics, so `fork` is going to be reasonably fast without needing to use `vfork`. Furthermore, `vfork` signal semantics are not at all standard across platforms. From `man vfork`:

> It is rather unfortunate that Linux revived this specter from the past. The BSD man page states:
>
> > This system call will be eliminated when proper system sharing mechanisms are implemented. Users should not depend on the memory sharing semantics of `vfork`() as it will, in that case, be made synonymous to `fork(2)`.
>
> Details of the signal handling are obscure and differ between systems. The BSD man page states:
>
> > To avoid a possible deadlock situation, processes that are children in the middle of a `vfork()` are never sent `SIGTTOU` or `SIGTTIN` signals; rather, output or `ioctl`s are allowed and input attempts result in an end-of-file indication.

That said, if used properly, `vfork` can be useful, and it will be faster on many other platforms. Linux does support it, so provided the code doesn't do anything that is restricted by `vfork`, it should be just fine on Linux.